# Why is kafka not creating a topic? bootstrap-server is not a recognized option

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-topic

I am new to Kafka and trying to create a new topic on my local machine.

I am following [this link](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart).

Here are the steps which i followed:

1. Start zookeeper

   ```
   bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
   ```
2. Start kafka-server

   ```
   bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
   ```
3. Create a topic

   ```
   bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
   ```

but when creating the topic, i am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: bootstrap-server is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:358)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:44)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

Is there any other configuration required to create a topic?
What wrong am i doing

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you use version older than 2.2 you should use `--zookeeper` option and pass connection string to zookeeper

Command would be something like that:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`

Comment: But the documentation uses bootstrap-server.

Comment: Documentation is for version 2.2. I suppose you are using version 2.1 or older one

Comment: Documentation is for 2.12 and i am using 2.11

Comment: `2.12` or `2.11` is scala version, not Kafka. `kafka_2.12-2.1.0` means it is 2.1.0 Kafka version