# Why is kafka not creating a topic? - is not a recognized option

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-topic

I am new to Kafka and trying to create a new topic on my local machine.
I am following this https://medium.com/@maftabali2k13/setting-up-a-kafka-cluster-on-ec2-1b37144cb4e

1. Start zookeeper

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh -daemon config/zookeeper.properties
```

Start kafka-server

```
bin/kafka-server-start.sh -daemon config/server.properties
```

Create a topic

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create -–bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -–replication-factor 1 -–partitions 1 --topic jerry
```

but when creating the topic, I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: – is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.validateOptionCharacters(OptionParser.java:633)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionCluster(OptionParser.java:528)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionToken(OptionParser.java:523)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:59)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:552)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:49)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

I had seen the following [Why is kafka not creating a topic? bootstrap-server is not a recognized option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494988/why-is-kafka-not-creating-a-topic-bootstrap-server-is-not-a-recognized-option)
But I cant find an answer to my problem here as the error given is different. Is there some stuff that I am missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used your command and had same issue:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create -–bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -–replication-factor 1 -–partitions 1 --topic jerry`

If you look closer to your command you will see, that before options: `bootstrap-server`, `replication-factor` and `partitions` are *strange* characters.

I think you use copy/paste method and some strange characters were added:

Following command should work:
`bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic jerry`

Best way is to write it by your own :).

Comment: Yaaa Thanks ..It worked . Yes I had done copy/paste. Just like u told, I there were some strange characters added.

Answer (score 1):

New version of Kafka no longer required ZooKeeper connection string. Use --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 instead of --zookeeper localhost:2181.

For windows: kafka-topics.bat --create -–bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -–replication-factor 1 -–partitions 1 --topic topic-name

For linux : kafka-topics.sh --create -–bootstrap-server localhost:9092 -–replication-factor 1 -–partitions 1 --topic topic-name

Answer (score -1):

In the latest version kafka_2.12-3.1.0 (2022) after unzipping and setting the properties and logs. keep the Kafka folder on the C drive and always run the command prompt with 'run as administrator'.
The .bat file is for windows

Terminal 1

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat
> ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties

Terminal 2

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat
> ..\..\config\server.properties

Terminal 3

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --topic tutorialspedia
> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

> `Created topic tutorialspedia.`

To checklist of topic created

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server
> localhost:9092
>
> `tutorialspedia`